# Managing Ribbon Actions Using jQuery SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, server-farm, csom

How to achieve the Ribbon Actions using jQuery or CSOM in SP 2013 farm.Am using On-Premises environment for implementing `Custom Actions`.

Comment: Do you want to create a new custom action or you want to override an existing ribbon action functionality?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint provides a Custom Action class, please read [SP.UserCustomActionCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408647(v=office.14).aspx).

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("stackoverflow")
var customAction = list.get_userCustomActions().add();

customAction.set_location('CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView');

var uiExtension = '<CommandUIExtension xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">' +
                    '<CommandUIDefinitions>' +
                        '<CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.List.CustomizeList.Controls._children">'+
                            '<Button Id="Ribbon.Documents.New.RibbonTest" '+
                                    'Command="Notify" '+
                                    'Sequence="0" '+
                                    'Image16by16="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_16x16.png" '+
                                    'Image32by32="/_layouts/images/NoteBoard_32x32.png" '+
                                    'Description="Uses the notification area to display a message." '+
                                    'LabelText="Notify hello" '+
                                    'TemplateAlias="o1"/>' +
                        '</CommandUIDefinition>'+
                    '</CommandUIDefinitions>'+
                    '<CommandUIHandlers>'+
                        '<CommandUIHandler Command="Notify" '+
                            'CommandAction="javascript:SP.UI.Notify.addNotification(\'Hello stackoverflow\');" />'+
                    '</CommandUIHandlers>'+
                   '</CommandUIExtension>';

customAction.set_commandUIExtension(uiExtension)


customAction.update();

context.load(list,'UserCustomActions');

context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
    console.log("success");
},
function(sender, args) {
    console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

I also found an interesting article when I was facing the same issue, I didn't implement the solution [provided by him](https://dbremes.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/theres-a-javascript-api-for-creating-ribbons/) but you surely can give a try.

Comment: Taran,Thanks for your sample code.Will go through the same and  revert here.

Comment: Taran,I need to add a  button kind of functionality for in this CustomAction.I will try this code.Thanks again.